# WSO2 Identity Server(5.9.0) - is it possible to access users from jdbc user store using embedded read only ldap?

Tags: ldap, camunda, wso2-identity-server

The Requirement is maintaining single JDBC(postgreSQL) user store for the below applications,

1. Create a user using SCIM api in to wso2-is.
2. Authenticate my microservices using oauth2 client of service provider.
3. Integrate WSO2-IS embedded read only LDAP for BPM(Camunda) application authentication and authorization.

I am able to do the first and second points and created a single JDBC user store for users.

`For the third point, not able to get the users from JDBC user store using embedded read only LDAP.`

Can you help me in this flow, is there any way available in wso2-is to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Note that embedded LDAP is not recommended in production :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the create a Read-only LDAP secondary user store for LDAP and use it for the BPM(Camunda) application authentication and authorization. You can find more information about secondary user store [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-secondary-user-stores/)

When authentication the users will be validated with all the existing user stores (primary and secondary). The possible issue will here is if the same username exists in two user stores.

If you provide user store name appended to the username, it will validate on the specific users.

For example, if the user store name is '`BPM`', then you need to append as  '`BPM/<username>`'

Comment: Thanks @senthalan. I understood the above use case but I am looking into single user store for all my applications. in my requirement I don't see the use of wso2 without having the single user data store.